# To use Tooltip in showconfirmDialog

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, joptionpane

I am trying to use the Tooltip feature of JButton in a Dialogue Box. I am using the showconfirmDialog feature.
The code is something like this

```
int optionSelection =  javax.swing.JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
    null,
    "you have selected XXX checkbox. This will edit YYY file.\n Do you wish to proceed?",
    null,
    javax.swing.JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
    javax.swing.JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
if (optionSelection == javax.swing.JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    //Do something here
} else if (optionSelection == javax.swing.JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
    //do something else here
} else {
    //do something different from the above two
}
```

But how do I add the toolTip feature for each of the Buttons? Should I create the `JOptionPane` and Buttons and then create the toolTip or is there any other alternative?

Comment: *"Awaiting response!"*  Awaiting payment!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with a `showConfirmDialog()`, however if you use `showOptionDialog` you can pass `Object[]` as the last argument as the options. If those are instances of `Component` the JOptionPane will use them instead of creating its own buttons.